# Can't add UI elements to Android Studio TV app

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, android-fragments, element, television

After creating a new TV app and going to the Design window I can't add any UI elements such as buttons or textviews. The TV screen is just greyed out and doesn't accept any element. There's an error message bellow saying Unknown fragments and allowing me to "Pick Layout" but picking any of the options provide still doesn't resolve anything.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I have no idea what is.

Comment: google it because your question is going to be downvoted. Google your error...

Comment: I did google it and found no solution. One answer said to just Pick a Layout from the error message but as I said that doesn't work for me. There seem to be extremely few results for ""unknown ragments" android studio" in general.

Comment: To me creating a new projects that produces error seems like something is setup wrong in android studio maybe a missing plugin ( I am just guessing) . Or in order to add something in layout you have to add something else first.  What I would do it would be to go view the simplest youtube tutorial step by step of a similar problem using the same tools.

Comment: I did, and despite putting variations of "tv" "tv app" etc. to get exact matches, the tutorials I'm getting are about mobile apps for which I have no issue with the UI elements or if they're about TV, they're not in  depth and with the part I need,  I shouldn't have such problems with a simple thing and yet it happens... I'll continue searching I guess.

Comment: I am sorry I wish I knew how to help you ... I upvote your question so more can see it...